# Add app icon on Contact not working in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-contacts

I am adding icon of my app in phonebook. now the problem is that its working fine in Api level < 23 but not working on Api level > 23.

> in API 23 it creates new Contact with number.

**in Api 21**
[image: Api 21]

**in Api 23**
[image]

```
String MIMETYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/com.appiconincontact";

    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                // insert account name and account type


                ops.add(
                        ContentProviderOperation
                                .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, true))
                                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, Constants.ACCOUNT_NAME)
                                .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, Constants.ACCOUNT_TYPE)
                                .withValue(RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE, RawContacts.AGGREGATION_MODE_DEFAULT)
                                .build()
                );


                // insert contact number
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, number)
                        .build());

                // insert mime-type data
                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(addCallerIsSyncAdapterParameter(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true))
                        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, MIMETYPE)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA2, Constants.APP_NAME)
                        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.DATA3, "User Connected with " + number)
                        .build());

                try {
                    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a **new** `RawContact`, and hoping that the system aggregates it into an existing `Contact`.

You're missing the "please attach this new raw-contact into this existing contact" part.

To do that you need to add an [AggregationExceptions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.AggregationExceptions.html).

First, find the current `RawContact IDs` in the `Contact` you wish to add to, then add a line to `AggregationExceptions` that links between your new `RawContact._ID` (`raw1`) and an existing `RawContact._ID` (`raw2`)

```
Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI);
builder.withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER);
builder.withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, raw1);
builder.withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, raw2);
ops.add(builder.build());
```

**EDIT**

If you want to add this code to your existing batch:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<>();
// insert account name and account type
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert( ... ).build());
// insert contact number
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert( ... ).build());
// insert mime-type data
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert( ... ).build());

// add an AggregationExceptions line 
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(AggregationExceptions.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(AggregationExceptions.TYPE, AggregationExceptions.TYPE_KEEP_TOGETHER)
    .withValueBackReference(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID1, 0)
    .withValue(AggregationExceptions.RAW_CONTACT_ID2, theRawContactIdOfTheExistingContact)
    .build());

try {
   resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch (Exception e) { ... }
```

The only thing you need to fill in here is `theRawContactIdOfTheExistingContact`, note that it's **not** a contact-id, it's a **raw-contact-id**, you'll need to put the right value there, depending on the rest of your code, and how you find the contact to add your data to.

Comment: added code that shows how this operation fits in with your existing batch

Comment: i m creating **raw-contact_id** using this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19675279/getting-rawcontact-id-using-contact-id but not working

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution but now I am facing another issue:  I can't open  my application from custom raw in android contacts list. What should I need to mention in my intent filters?

Comment: @AndiM that depends on what you added in your custom mimetype data row. you can check logcat for tag "ActivityManager" when clicking that row in the contact, to see which exact intent it sends, so you can change your intent-filters accordingly.

Comment: @marmor I cant find any log when I tap on my custom row. It only shows me a toast with message "No application found to handle this action". Can you please show some code snippet to achieve this?

Comment: make sure you don't have any filter on the LogCat, don't use "show only selected application" filter

Comment: Yes I am doing only that.